# Discord Bot won't reply to messages in channel

Tags: python, discord

I'm not sure what is wrong with my python code, but I've been trying to get this to work wit ha bunch of different variations for a couple days now. The bot launches and goes online, but whenever I try to input a command into discord, the bot never responds. I've tried in multiple servers as well as my own. Here is my code:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
        await message.channel.send("Hello!")

client.run("original token would be here")
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code (if it's complete), it seems like you're missing a necessary part, which are your intents.
Did you declare them somewhere in the code?

You also have to set the permissions you want the bot to have when joining the server, under [discord.com/developers/applications/](https://discord.com/developers/applications/)

`In version 1.5 comes the introduction of Intents. This is a radical change in how bots are written. An intent basically allows a bot to subscribe to specific buckets of events.`

Source: [Discordpy ReadTheDocs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html?highlight=import%20discord)

```
import discord

intent = discord.Intents.all()
client = discord.Client(intents = intent)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {client.user}')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.name == client.user: return

    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')

client.run('TOKEN GOES HERE')
```

[image]

Additionally, you might want to check the documentation for discord.ext in order to implement @bot.commands and avoid hard coding the command followed by message conditionals.